# Has this Mongo Query to be really so slow?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, query-optimization

I am struggling with a MongoDB query. The records' structure is really easy:

```
{ body: "Some sentence, no more than 4-5 lines I would say", title: "Just some characters", date: "2021-10-17 11:11:11" }
```

By now we have 800k records. When searching for uncommon words, the search is very very quick and results are given just after some ms, as expected. However, if using very common words, which may appear even in the most of records, the search itself can take up to 15 seconds.

The code I use is:

```
var queryString = "aVeryCommonWord";


db1.collection("nic_news").createIndex({
    title: "text",
    body: "text"
})

query = {
    $text: {
        $search: queryString
    },
    date: {
        $gt: "2021-10-17"
    } ,
 }

var skipInt = 0;

db1.collection("nic_news").find(query).skip(skipInt).sort({
    date: -1
}).limit(25).toArray(function (err, doc) {
```

...

Even if I limit the results by number and date, like in the code above, I got no less than 15 seconds to see results in console.

Any idea on how to optimize this search?

Thank you very much!

Comment: MongoDB is not a search engine, it's a database. Its primary goal is to store documents. Granted, you can do some basic querying, aggregation, etc. but if you really are looking into advanced and high-performance search, you should add something specifically designed for this, like Elasticsearch.

Comment: Also, you query the `date` field, but it is not indexed. That's probably why your query is taking ages.

Comment: Also also, your `date` field is not a Mongo `ISODate`, it is a simple string. That's probably another reason why your query is slow, you are comparing strings, not dates.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your comments. So, in some way, granted that things could be better in the DB itself, I understand that Mongo can be very slow in such situations. is this correct? Thanks for your time.

Comment: BTW, the date is an ISO date. What you see in my post is a string, but actually in the real DB it is an ISO date. Even deleting the date from the query, the search is slow (about 15 seconds). Thanks.

Comment: What about the date field not being indexed?

Comment: You could try `query = { text : /aVeryCommonWord/ }`. Mongo supports regexes natively

Comment: Actually the search with $or aggregation (not a FST, but on title and body fields) with regex takes less than 4 seconds, to my surprise.